# Add drop shadow to TextFormField when error is showing flutter

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I'm having trouble adding a drop shadow to TextFormField especially when there is an error showing up.

I Wrapped my TextFormField inside a Material widget and it works fine except when there is an error the field is padded up and the error message is placed under it making the shadow containing both of them.

Is there a way I can solve this?
[Error Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ZTh.png)

Here is my code:

```
Material(
  elevation: 5,
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: TextFormField(
    focusNode: _focus,
    controller: widget.controller,
    validator: widget.validator,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      hintText: widget.hint,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54195097/8023701

Comment: It looks good until you don't use `helperText` or `errorText`. Otherwise, shadow occupies an additional place and it looks not good, that's the problem. @Nbn