# textFormField borders with shadows

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, textformfield

I'm new to flutter. I just saw this beautiful design and therefore I've been trying to implement something like attached below -
[image]

Unfortunately, I've been unable to do so after a lot of tries with InputBorders, Material widget etc.

Can someone please let me know how we can implement such textFormFields with the exact same design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [neumorphic](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic) package, You can achieve a similar effect using this package.

```
 Neumorphic(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, top: 2, bottom: 4),
          style: NeumorphicStyle(
            depth: NeumorphicTheme.embossDepth(context),
            boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.stadium(),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14, horizontal: 18),
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: this.widget.onChanged,
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: this.widget.hint),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at [TextField docs on Flutter API](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html), there's the `decoration` property.

---

**Blurred effect in borders**

This property is the class `InputDecoration` (read [its API](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)).

To add a simple border, in the `border` property (classes [Border](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Border-class.html) and for each side of the border the class [BorderSide](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderSide-class.html)) see the code below.

```dart
Border(
      top: BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade50),
      bottom: BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900),
),
```

Border class has a `color` property, you can use it with `Colors.blue[50]` to do a blurred effect or a higher number. Read [Colors class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html).

---

**Shadow style**

[image]
To do these shadows, you can use the properties `contentPadding`, `enabledBorder` and `border`. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54195097/9192954. It uses `InputDecoration` (the code is from 2019, then `borderSide` currently doesn't exist, instead use `border`).

Hope this helps you.