# flutter textFormField shrinks when error is raised

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

please check out this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZoGB.jpg
the text field shrinks weirdly when an error is raised by the validitor How can I FIX THAT ?
here is part of loginScreen Class code
is it because I've wrapped the textField with material ? this is the only way I figured to get it look like what I want

```
      Container(
          height: 486,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration:  const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
           Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children:  [
                 Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 50, 23, 16),
                  child: Material(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty? 'Enter an email': null,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        setState(() {
                          email = val ;
                        });

                      },
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color:Color(0xFFB3B3B3),width: 0.3)),
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                        iconColor: Colors.white54,
                        hintText: 'email address',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                 Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 0, 23, 5),
                  child: Material(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: (value) => value!.length < 6 ? 'Enter a password 6+ charts long': null,
                      obscureText: true,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        setState(() {
                          password = val ;
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color:Color(0xFFB3B3B3),width: 0.3)),
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                        iconColor: Colors.white54,
                        hintText: 'password',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**error 1**

to remove over flow in the bottom use SingleChildScrollView so the code should be like this

```
   Container(
            height: 486,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
            child:
              SingleChildScrollView (child:
             Column(children: [
              Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(children: [
etc
```

by doing that it will resolve the overflow error from validation expansion

**error 2**

check the link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68986217/17180860

using this answer it's possible to do with out validation expansion issue