# How to add border shadow to a TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, border, textfield, elevation

how to add border or elevation to a textfield in flutter

I wanted to give a shadow to my text field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add drop shadow to TextFormField In Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194347/how-to-add-drop-shadow-to-textformfield-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

After some digging i found the answer to my question.
here is my code :
// This is a single TextField

// Wrap your TextField around Material Widget and give border radius and // elevaiton to Material Widget.

```
Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 8),
          child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 250,
                child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  elevation: 8,
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'First Name',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

> `Blockquote`

```
 // IF YOU WANT TO USE THE DESIGN IN THE IMAGE THEN USE THIS CODE ://
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:signup_figma/Screens/signin_personal_details_screen.dart';

import '../Widgets/otp_pin_input_field.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignUpScreen> createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  bool mobileNumberVerify = false;
  bool emailVerify = false;
  bool checkBoxValue = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, left: 20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: const [
                    /////// SignUp///////////
                    Text(
                      "Sign up",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Create an account to get started",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

        

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 8),
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 250,
                child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  elevation: 8,
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'First Name',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 250,
                child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  elevation: 8,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      // fillColor: Colors.white,
                      //   filled: true,
                      labelText: 'Last Name',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 250,
                height: 50,
                child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  elevation: 8,
                  child: TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                        suffixIcon: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, top: 15),
                          child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                print("Clicked");
                                setState(() {
                                  mobileNumberVerify = true;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Text("verify")),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 36, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Text(
                  "Resend OTP",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            mobileNumberVerify
                ? OtpPinInputField()
                : SizedBox(
                    height: 2,
                  ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 250,
                height: 50,
                child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  elevation: 8,
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: ' Email',
                        suffixIcon: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, top: 15),
                          child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                print("Clicked");
                                setState(() {
                                  emailVerify = true;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Text("verify")),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 36, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Text(
                  "Resend OTP",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            emailVerify
                ? OtpPinInputField()
                : SizedBox(
                    height: 2,
                  ),

            Row(
              children: [
                Checkbox(
                    value: checkBoxValue,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.checkBoxValue = value!;
                      });
                    }),
                Container(
                  width: 320,
                  child: RichText(
                    text: const TextSpan(
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "I've read and agree with the ",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: 'Terms & Conditions, Privacy Policy',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent)),
                        TextSpan(text: ' & '),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: 'End User License Agreement',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: MaterialButton(
                height: 50,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PersonalDetailsScreen()),
                  );
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11)),
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => PersonalDetailsScreen()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    "Register",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Blockquote

Create a file otpPininputfield.dart and paste this code :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class OtpPinInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  const OtpPinInputField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Form(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35,right: 40),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children:  [
              SizedBox(
                height: 45,
                width: 45,
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(

                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                    )
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value){
                    if(value.length == 1){
                      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                    }
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,

                  inputFormatters: [
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 45,
                width: 45,
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                      )
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value){
                    if(value.length == 1){
                      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                    }
                  },
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  inputFormatters: [
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                  ],
                ),
              ),    SizedBox(
                height: 45,
                width: 45,
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                      )
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value){
                    if(value.length == 1){
                      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                    }
                  },
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  inputFormatters: [
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                  ],
                ),
              ),    SizedBox(
                height: 45,
                width: 45,
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                      )
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value){
                    if(value.length == 1){
                      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                    }
                  },
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  inputFormatters: [
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.....

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[400]),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[600]),
        ),
        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red[600]),
        ),
        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red[800]),
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        fillColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey[800],
        fontSize: 16.0,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            blurRadius: 10.0,
            spreadRadius: 5.0,
            offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).